# selecting the regular expression matches inversely

Tags: javascript, regex

I am practicing regular expression selections to select some pattern out of a text. I can easily select a pattern but as I am new I am finding it hard to select all the other text except the pattern described.

For example : **\d{0}[0]\d{0,1}[56789]\d{8}** this pattern gets the numbers in my desired way of pattern. but how can I get the inverse selection? I mean how can i select the whole text except the matched expression?

Comment: you can replace or split the string by the RegEx

Comment: example would be better

Comment: What is the purpose of `\d{0}`? Why did you put `[0]` in square brackets when it only contains one character? `{0,1}` can be rewritten as `?`. `[56789]` can be rewritten as `[5-9]`.

Comment: i want to check if the pattern starts with 0 if it starts with 0 then it will look if the next two is in within 5 to 9 and if its true the rest are some digits.

Comment: how about selecting all the other texts rather than the matched pattern?like I dont want the matched pattern, I  want everything other than the pattern. please have a look : https://regex101.com/r/8U6kSE/3

Comment: I was pointing out parts of your pattern that indicate misunderstandings of regex. Your original pattern is functionally identical to `0\d?[5-9]\d{8}`.

Answer (score 0):

For example if the pattern is `\d`:

```js
console.log( 'a1!'.replace(/\d/, '') )     // "a!"
console.log( 'a1!'.split(/\d/) )           // ["a", "!"]

console.log( 'a1!'.match(/(.*?)\d(.*)/) )  // ["a1!", "a", "!"]
console.log( /(.*?)\d(.*)/.exec('a1!') )   // ["a1!", "a", "!"]
```

`.*`  matches any character(s) as many times as possible

`.*?` matches any character(s) as few times as possible

`()` captures the match in a group

The first result in the `.match` and `.exec` results is the whole match, and the two results after it are the captured groups `(.*?)` and `(.*)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the string without the numbers, just replace the numbers
with nothing.  If you want to see it all but separate the numbers from the
rest, use the below regex.

---

Select everything then exclude what you don't want.
Example `/(.*?)(\d{0}[0]\d{0,1}[56789]\d{8}|$)/g` will get everything,
where capture group 1 contains what is not your regex (that you don't want).

```js
var str = 'hello world 088111 this is a 0592222 test';
console.log( str.replace( /(?=.)(.*?)(0[5-9]{2}\d+|$)/g, '$1') );
```

Output: `Hello world  this is a  test`